# How can I get a hold of the element ref in a directive associated with it? Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a directive that binds to a component variable and is used in it's template. I want to be able to reference the element that is using it.

e.g. component template using directive

```
<div [directiveBinding]="componentVar"></div>
```

e.g. directive

```
export class MyDirective {
    @Input('directiveBinding') varFromComponent;
}
```

How can I reference the div element ref in the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should inject `ElementRef` inside the constructor. To access the `HTMLDivElement`, use `this.elementRef.nativeElement`

```
export class MyDirective {
    @Input('directiveBinding') varFromComponent;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
}
```